# How to implement change text size dynamically in android text views using Android studio (java and XML)?

Tags: android

How to implement change text size dynamically in android text views using Android studio (java and XML)? Developing a book-type app.

Comment: Try to do some research before asking a question, Use setTextSize() to change the text size programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of the text in a `TextView` [via `setTextSize()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(int,%20float)).

Comment: I need to change text in a view, visible to  user, to enable an action bar button to change it